# Running with python instead of python3 in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I run Linux via ubuntu in windows. My terminal has python3 instead of python. I am using a package named PASTA, which uses commands with python as:

```
python run_pasta.py -i input_fasta
```

Since, I have python3, I am trying to run it this way:

```
python3 run_pasta.py -i ALL_FASTA.fasta -d protein --aligner=probcons
```

which gives me the following error, could anyone please tell how to fix this?

> PASTA INFO: Performing initial alignment of the entire data matrix...
> PASTA failed because one of the programs it tried to run failed. The
> invocation that failed was:
> "/mnt/f/Projects/WoldringLab/AnalyzingGenerativeModel/pasta-code/pasta/bin/hmmeralign"
> "/home/aryaman3900/.pasta/pastajob/temp569cp9x3/init_aln/temphmmeralignourpmnyw/input.fasta"
> "/home/aryaman3900/.pasta/pastajob/temp569cp9x3/init_aln/query-0.fasta"
> "/home/aryaman3900/.pasta/pastajob/temp569cp9x3/init_aln/temphmmeralignourpmnyw/input.aligned"
> "amino"
>
> **/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a symlink (*symbolical link*) from `python3` to `python`. What this will do is just to map each call to `/usr/bin/python` to your python3 executable:

```
sudo ln -s $(which python3) /usr/bin/python
```

You can learn more about the `ln` command by reading its man page via `man ln`.